# Setting Up Kafka Cluster In Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, bitnami, docker-network

Hey I am using the Bitnami kafka image to create a kafka cluster for testing purposes on my local machine. I've tried following the docs best I could and this is what I came up with:

```
version: "3"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka1:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    container_name: 'kafka1'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_ID=0
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  kafka2:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    container_name: 'kafka2'
    ports:
     - '9093:9093'
    environment:
     - KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_ID=1
     - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9093
     - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9093
     - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
     - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
     - zookeeper
```

With the above config in my docker-compose.yml file I get the following errors:

```
kafka1       | [2021-09-27 01:19:29,963] WARN [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=1] Connection to node 1 (/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
kafka1       | [2021-09-27 01:19:30,066] WARN [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=1] Connection to node 1 (/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
kafka1       | [2021-09-27 01:19:30,117] INFO [broker-0-to-controller-send-thread]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use broker 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
kafka1       | [2021-09-27 01:19:30,169] WARN [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=1] Connection to node 1 (/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
kafka1       | [2021-09-27 01:19:30,271] WARN [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=1] Connection to node 1 (/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
kafka1       | [2021-09-27 01:19:30,373] WARN [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=1] Connection to node 1 (/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
kafka1       | [2021-09-27 01:19:30,477] WARN [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=1] Connection to node 1 (/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
kafka1       | [2021-09-27 01:19:30,582] WARN [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=1] Connection to node 1 (/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
kafka1       | [2021-09-27 01:19:30,685] WARN [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=1] Connection to node 1 (/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
kafka1       | [2021-09-27 01:19:30,790] WARN [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=1] Connection to node 1 (/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

These errors continue forever as I assume the brokers are attempting to connect to each other. The idea was to have a broker running on localhost:9092 and another on localhost:9093. I'm surely doing something wrong, so please let me know if I am missing something fundamentally here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently `KAFKA_LISTENERS` is not a valid variable anymore. Did you see this? https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka#111-debian-9-r205-220-debian-9-r40-111-ol-7-r286-and-220-ol-7-r53

Comment: Also, you are setting the listeners to `127.0.0.1` so that's probably another issue.